# Optimise use of multiple user defined functions in join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Working in SQL Server 2016 (v13).

I am performing a left join between two tables (tblA and tblB) where the join condition includes multiple user defined scalar functions (UDFs). The UDFs take a parameter from tblA and tblB. I don't know if or how to optimise the query.

The (reduced) query is along the lines of:

```
   select *
     from tblA A
left join tblB B 
       on 1 = dbo.udf1(A.field1, B.anotherField1)
      and 1 = dbo.udf2(A.field2, B.anotherField2)
```

As an example, dbo.udf1 and dbo.udf2 are something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf1 (@p1 VARCHAR(100), @p2 VARCHAR(100))
  RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result BIT;
    SELECT @result = IIF(@p1 LIKE @p2, 1, 0);
    RETURN(@result)
END
```

The UDFs are naturally a bit more complex, but are both written as a single `SELECT` (i.e., both are INLINE functions).

I cannot find a way to rework this into a form making use of table value functions. I'm assuming that there must be a way to improve this query, but not sure if there is, or how to start.

Comment: Using a scalar UDF in your `ON` is going to cause your query to become non-SARGable (and scalar UDF's have a reputation of being slow as well). Considering you state that that isn't the actual logic of your UDF, we'd be better off knowing what it is, and seeing if we can change it to proper boolean logic. As it stands, however, your query will only be as fast as a scan of both your tables, with the UDFs applied against **every** value in the columns (most likely 1 row at a time, but the query plan would tell us otherwise; but that isn't going to help things here).

Comment: The way to optimise UDF's in joins is to **avoid** UDF's in joins. It just isn't possible to offer any viable alternative without the real UDF code AND **sample data** and **the expected result** (based on the sample data).

Comment: thank you both - your points have helped narrow down my concern substantially. together with the answer below, i have a few routes to try, although i suspect that they'll be performance constrained for the reasons you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot find a way to rework this into a form making use of table value functions.

This is possible. Note, that this logic requires quadratically comparing all rows from A to all rows from B. This is necessarily rather slow.

So rewrite as follows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B
CROSS APPLY dbo.MyPredicate(A.x, B.y) p
WHERE p.SomeValue = 1
```

The `CROSS JOIN` is the quadratic comparison. After the join you have the values from both tables available to execute the join condition.

Comment: this wouldn't give precisely the same results as the query in my original post, but it would be a small step to perform a left join between tblA and your (inner) query above. thanks - this has given me a place to start experimenting!

Comment: @pcbulldozer right, I did not notice that it is a left join. You should be able to make it work with outer apply. The apply operations are strictly more powerful that the join operations. The outer apply must be a derived table and the predicate pushed into that derived table.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks - the outer apply didn't occur to me immediately at all. Appreciated!